# How can I use a parameter to a protractor configuration file to chose steps?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, testing, protractor

Following the lead of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29406962/can-i-access-parameters-in-my-protractor-configuration-file), I tried (naievely) to do this:

`protractor test/features/protractor-conf.js --params.test_set=dev_test`

and

protractor-conf.js:

```
exports.config = {
   // ...
  specs: [browser.params.test_set+'/*.feature'],
```

... but of course it doesn't work because browser is not defined at the time that the conf file is parse.

So how could I achieve this effect: passing a parameter to protractor that determines the specs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `--specs` command-line argument:

> `--specs` Comma-separated list of files to test

```
protractor test/features/protractor-conf.js --specs=dev_test/*.feature
```

Note that `dev_test/*.feature` would be passed into the protractor's command-line-interface which would resolve the paths based on the current working directory ([source code](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/cli.js#L112)).

Comment: Fingers crossed - this looks exactly what I'm after.   I'm about to explore this, but I fear the syntax can't quite be right, because we want to pass the wildcard in to protractor, not have the shell expand it?

Comment: @GreenAsJade okay, I've quickly tried something similar. In my case it was `protractor test/e2e/config/local.conf.js --specs=test/e2e/specs/*.js` and it worked for me.

Comment: Wierd, I just found the same.  I don't understand why, but ... yay :)   At least this point of concern is addressed for others now.  I'd love to know why it works... I guess there's a stack of stuff going on during invocation that I haven't delved into what is processing what...

Comment: @GreenAsJade shell is not expanding the paths here - the glob pattern is passed into the protractor command line interface as a string which is further processed and passed to the task scheduler. I've added some explanation, hope that clears things up a bit..